# Add UIImage to back View

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, uiview, uiimageview

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOe7EP4DD3yN0tvNTlKZmdPQzA0WWVPZ25DSDZaaVRHdkk4/view?usp=sharing)

Hey :) Im kind of new to Stack and not sure if i should have edited this instead of adding a whole new question but i figured out a way to make it more clear.  So in my code i want my textImages to only show up on the front of the UIimageViews, and the "back" image to show up on only the back side of my ImageView when flipped.  Right now both Images are showing up on both parts.  Is there a way to addSubview() to only the back of the ImagView :/ I do not want to use UItablevView if possible.  Also in the video the last looped UIimageView works just like i want but not the ImageViews before it.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var open: UIBarButtonItem! 

    var myImageArray = [UIImage]()
    var back: UIImageView!
    var front: UIImageView!

    var showingFront = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapped))
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        mainScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
        mainScrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
        myImageArray = [textImg1, textImg2 ,textImg3, textImg4, textImg5]

        for i in 0..<myImageArray.count {
            front = UIImageView()
            front.image = myImageArray[i]
            front.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            let yPosition = self.view.frame.height * CGFloat(i) + self.view.frame.height/2 - (self.view.frame.height / 1.1)/2
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width/2 - (self.view.frame.width / 1.1)/2
            front.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: self.view.frame.width / 1.1, height: self.view.frame.height / 1.1)
            front.layer.borderWidth = 5

            mainScrollView.contentSize.height = mainScrollView.frame.height * CGFloat(i + 1)
            mainScrollView.addSubview(front)

            back = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "back.png"))
            back.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            back.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: self.view.frame.width / 1.1, height: self.view.frame.height / 1.1)
            back.layer.borderWidth = 5
            mainScrollView.addSubview(back)

        }
    }

    func tapped() {
        print("Hello")
        if (showingFront) {
            UIView.transition(from: front, to: back, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
            showingFront = false
        } else {
            UIView.transition(from: back, to: front, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
            showingFront = true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `mainScrollView.bringSubview(toFront: front)`

Comment: yes, it remove it, no longer visible.  that function doesn't''t work the way it sounds aha :)

Comment: How about adding the `back` `UIImageView` and `front` `UIImageView` to the storyboard on top of the `UIScrollView` rather than creating them from code.